# Trouble understanding the maths/code used within this algorithm for camera movement in java

Tags: java, math, camera, game-development

I am programming a game in java with reference to youtube videos and have come across some code and algorithms that I don't quite understand.

```
private float x, y;

public Camera(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void tick(GameObject object) {
    x += ((object.getX() - x) - 1000 / 2) * 0.05f;
    y += ((object.getY() - y) - 563 / 2) * 0.05f;

    System.out.println(x);

    if (x <= 0)
        x = 0;
    if (x >= 1032)
        x = 1032;
    if (y <= 0)
        y = 0;
    if (y >= 563 + 48)
        y = 563 + 48;
}

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
 }

}
```

Now, I understand everything here except this

```
x += ((object.getX() - x) - 1000 / 2) * 0.05f;
y += ((object.getY() - y) - 563 / 2) * 0.05f;
```

which is within the tick method. The method is what updates the camera to follow the player around the screen. The GameObject parameter is parsed in as the player object. How do the cameras x and y follow the player with this algorithm? Why do we subtract players x/y by the cameras x/y and then all multiplied by a float. I get the subtracting the windows width / 2 and height / 2 centers the player in the middle of the screen part.
The float is what gives the camera a smoother feel according to RealtutsGML. It's not strictly fixed on the players position, it slides along a little. But why does * 0.05 make this happen?
Then in the game class inside the main rendering method the cameras getX and getY method alongside the graphics2D's translate method are to determine where the camera moves within the game.

```
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 563);

    g2d.translate(-camera.getX(), -camera.getY());

    handler.render(g);

    g2d.translate(camera.getX(), camera.getY());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the screen center will be at the coordinates `(x + 1000 / 2, y + 563 / 2)`. With this in mind, let's take a closer look at the formula (only the x part; y is exactly the same):

```
x += ((object.getX() - x) - 1000 / 2) * 0.05f;
```

Re-arranging the parenthesis, we get:

```
x += (object.getX() - (x + 1000 / 2)) * 0.05f;
```

We see that the screen center is right there. Let us substitute it with the variable `c` to make things clearer:

```
x += (object.getX() - c) * 0.05f;
```

The first term `object.getX() - c` is the difference between the object's position and the screen center. Hence, if the object is centered, this difference is zero. This is exactly the amount that we need to move the camera to exactly center the object. And if we had

```
x += (object.getX() - c);
```

... we would always keep the object at the screen center. But we have a factor of `0.05` there. Hence, we are not moving the camera by the entire distance. Only by a fraction of it. I.e., we are moving the object closer to the screen center. If it is far away, it will move fast (because the difference is large). If it is already close, it will move slowly (because the difference is small). The factor of `0.05` is setting how immediate the centering will be. A factor of `0` would not move the object at all, a factor of `1` would immediately center the object. Everything in between represents a smooth motion with different accelerations. You can imagine this factor as the stiffness of a spring between the screen center and the object.

Comment: Ahhhhh I see. Why do we  g2d.translate(-camera.getX(), -camera.getY()); and  g2d.translate(camera.getX(), camera.getY());

Why does there need to be two translations, one negative and the other positive?

Comment: The first moves the coordinate system to the camera location. The second restores the original coordinate system.